# Identify Which Accordion Panel is Open Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a standard bootstrap 3 accordion panel with a dynamic number of panels. I need to display another div with information specific to the panel that is open. I have trapped the open event and tried to identify the calling panel with the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', "#accordion_a", function(){ 
    $('#accordion_a').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        alert('Calling #' + e.currentTarget.id);
    })
})
```

However it just returns the parent panel set "#accordion_a." (and for some reason fires multiple times) So how can I identify which panel is open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are some issue in your javascript, I would suggest to use the

```
$(function() {});
```

instead of

```
$(document).on('click', "#accordion_a", function(){});
```

And then the event **shown.bs.collapse** must be triggered on the "collapse" block not on a link.

Please check this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/V8h9a/ 
And let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: That works great! I could not find this answer anywhere